# compute an average of the last two columns which differ for all subjects

Tags: r, conditional-statements, average

I'm an R beginner and it's my first post here. I'm struggling with a problem and would love your advice. Basically, I have a dataset with 3 sets of columns that I need to manipulate altogether in order to obtain the desired outcome, which is an average of the 2 most recent observations (and that these observations must occur after a cutoff date, say, 3/15/2018) that are of high quality, but what makes it complex is that the relevant columns that go into the average differ for all cases.

- The first set of data columns has to do with the number of observations each case has, so subject one has 2 observations, subject two has 3, etc.
- The second set of columns describe the data quality for each of these  observations.  So for example, subject 1 has two good observations whereas subject 2 has 1 bad data quality for the first observation and good data quality for the 2 latter ones, and subject 3 has 3 observations that are of good quality and one observation (obs_3)that is of bad data quality.
- The third set of columns specify the dates of the observations.

  ```
    subject_id obs_1 obs_2 obs_3 obs_4 obs_1_dq obs_2_dq obs_3_dq obs_4_dq obs_1_date obs_2_date obs_3_date obs_4_date desired.average
  1          1     5     6    NA    NA     TRUE     TRUE       NA       NA 2018-02-01 2018-03-16       <NA>       <NA>              NA
  2          2     6     8    11    NA    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE       NA 2018-02-18 2018-03-16 2018-04-10       <NA>             9.5
  3          3     7     9    12    15     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE 2018-02-15 2018-03-18 2018-04-02 2018-04-10            12.0
  4          4     3     4     8    15     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE 2018-02-16 2018-03-08 2018-03-10 2018-03-15              NA
  ```

In order to compute an average of TWO latest observations that are of good data quality:

1. I must first decide which observations are of good quality,
2. Then, compute an average (and it has to be an average of 2 observations) that occur after 3/15 and they must be the two most recent observations.

Below is my sample dataset.  I've tried to do this manually in Excel and it was really painstaking.  I'm hoping to do this in R and would very much appreciate your feedback. Thank you!

```
Here is my sample dataset: 
> dput(head(df,5))

structure(list(subject_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), obs_1 = c(5, 6, 7, 
3), obs_2 = c(6, 8, 9, 4), obs_3 = c(NA, 11, 12, 8), obs_4 = c(NA, 
NA, 15, 15), obs_1_dq = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), obs_2_dq = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), obs_3_dq = c(NA, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), obs_4_dq =    
c(NA, 
NA, TRUE, TRUE), obs_1_date = structure(c(17563, 17580, 17577, 
17578), class = "Date"), obs_2_date = structure(c(17606, 17606, 
17608, 17598), class = "Date"), obs_3_date = structure(c(NA, 
17631, 17623, 17600), class = "Date"), obs_4_date = structure(c(NA, 
NA, 17631, 17605), class = "Date"), desired.average = c(NA, 9.5, 
12, NA)), .Names = c("subject_id", "obs_1", "obs_2", "obs_3", 
"obs_4", "obs_1_dq", "obs_2_dq", "obs_3_dq", "obs_4_dq", "obs_1_date", 
"obs_2_date", "obs_3_date", "obs_4_date", "desired.average"), row.names   
= c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should also work, and though a bit verbose it doesn't rely on column indices, so should be robust:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

num_date <- as.numeric(as.Date("2018-03-15"))

df <- df[,-ncol(df)]

df_join <- df %>%
  gather(Obs, value, 2:ncol(df)) %>%
  mutate(
    nr = as.numeric(gsub("[^\\d]", "", Obs, perl = TRUE))
  ) %>%
  group_by(subject_id, nr) %>%
  filter(!(is.na(value) | (grepl("_dq", Obs) & value == 0) | any(value[grepl("_date", Obs)] <= num_date))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(subject_id, Obs) %>%
  filter(!row_number() < (max(row_number() - 1))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(subject_id) %>%
  mutate(
    desired.average = mean(value[grepl("_date|_dq", Obs) == FALSE], na.rm = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  filter(!max(row_number()) == 3) %>%
  distinct(subject_id, desired.average)

df <- left_join(df, df_join)
```

Result:

```
  subject_id obs_1 obs_2 obs_3 obs_4 obs_1_dq obs_2_dq obs_3_dq obs_4_dq obs_1_date obs_2_date
1          1     5     6    NA    NA     TRUE     TRUE       NA       NA 2018-02-01 2018-03-16
2          2     6     8    11    NA    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE       NA 2018-02-18 2018-03-16
3          3     7     9    12    15     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE 2018-02-15 2018-03-18
4          4     3     4     8    15     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE 2018-02-16 2018-03-08
  obs_3_date obs_4_date desired.average
1       <NA>       <NA>              NA
2 2018-04-10       <NA>             9.5
3 2018-04-02 2018-04-10            12.0
4 2018-03-10 2018-03-15              NA
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Your code worked for me as well.  There are a lot of functions that are new to me, so I'll take some time to digest what you did.  Thank you so much for your time and insights on this!

Comment: Thanks @Anita! You can accept the answer or just upvote if you consider it useful :-)

Comment: Sure, arg0naut! I accepted your answer and tried to upvote it too, but I got a message saying that votes that are cast with less than 15 reputation points is recorded but not displayed :(.  So sorry about that.  But once again, so grateful for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad that it helped, we all have our questions and that's why Stack is good :-)

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you. Code is annotated briefly.

```
df=structure(list(subject_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), obs_1 = c(5, 6, 7, 
3), obs_2 = c(6, 8, 9, 4), obs_3 = c(NA, 11, 12, 8), obs_4 = c(NA, 
NA, 15, 15), obs_1_dq = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), obs_2_dq = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), obs_3_dq = c(NA, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), obs_4_dq =    
c(NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE), obs_1_date = structure(c(17563, 17580, 17577, 
17578), class = "Date"), obs_2_date = structure(c(17606, 17606, 
17608, 17598), class = "Date"), obs_3_date = structure(c(NA, 
17631, 17623, 17600), class = "Date"), obs_4_date = structure(c(NA, 
NA, 17631, 17605), class = "Date"), desired.average = c(NA, 9.5, 
12, NA)), .Names = c("subject_id", "obs_1", "obs_2", "obs_3", 
"obs_4", "obs_1_dq", "obs_2_dq", "obs_3_dq", "obs_4_dq", "obs_1_date", 
"obs_2_date", "obs_3_date", "obs_4_date", "desired.average"), row.names   
= c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

# separate each section
obs=df[,2:5]
dq=df[, 6:9]
dt=sapply(df[, 10:13], as.numeric) # for easier calculations
# remove bad quality
obs[dq==F]=NA
# remove dates before 2018-3-15
obs[dt - as.numeric(as.Date("2018-03-15")) <= 0] = NA
# only leave two most recent dates
dt[is.na(obs)]=NA
dt=t(apply(dt,1,function(x){x[x<max(x[x!=max(x, na.rm=T)],na.rm=T)]=NA;x}))
obs[is.na(dt)]=NA
# average
df$avg=apply(obs,1,function(x)ifelse(sum(!is.na(x))>=2, mean(x,na.rm=T), NA))
df
```

**Edits:**
Explanation

```
dt=t(apply(dt,1, function(x){x[x<max(x[x!=max(x, na.rm=T)],na.rm=T)]=NA;x}))
```

I think this might be a little confusing for `x[x<max(x[x!=max(x, na.rm=T)],na.rm=T)]=NA`. The `na.rm=T` meaning remove `NA` values. `max(x[x!=max(x)])` meaning the second largest number. So `x[x < 2nd_largest_num]=NA` just removed any number except the largest and the 2nd largest. This function is then applied to the data frame row-wise. The final result is `dt` contains only two largest number in each row (most recent date in numeric format). All "discarded" values (NA in dt) will be removed from `obs` in the next line `obs[is.na(dt)]=NA`. After all these, `obs` only contains the two recent values in each line.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was blown away by your code and wouldn't have figured all this out in a million years.  I followed everything you did except for this line: dt=t(apply(dt,1,function(x){x[x<max(x[x!=max(x, na.rm=T)],na.rm=T)]=NA;x})) which I couldn't even begin to parse to know what each piece means.  Can you please explain in plain English what each part of the code does?  I want to understand in order to apply that to similar problems in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: I spent sometime dissecting each piece of the code based on your clarification and I think I understand what you did.  Thank you again!